# Removing a white polygon from a filled parametric plot

Tags: plotting

I have the following function

```
partitionfunction[d_][q_] := 
  Piecewise[{
    {Sin[(Pi*q)/(2*d)]^2, Inequality[0, LessEqual, q, Less, d]}, 
    {1, Inequality[d, LessEqual, q, Less, 2*Pi - d]}, 
    {Sin[(Pi*(2*Pi - q))/(2*d)]^2, 2*Pi - d <= q <= 2*Pi}}]

radius[d_][q_] := 1 + 1.5*partitionfunction[d][q]*BesselJ[5, (13/(2*Pi))*q + 5]

curve[d_][q_] := radius[d][q]*{Cos[q], Sin[q]}
```

which I use to generate the following plot

```
ParametricPlot[curve[1][q], {q, 0, 2*Pi}, 
  Axes -> False, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.007]]
```

[image]

So far so good. But when I try to fill the enclosed area, I get a strange white polygon.

```
ParametricPlot[curve[1][q], {q, 0, 2*Pi}, 
  Axes -> False, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.007]] /. 
  Line[l_List] :> {{Orange, Polygon[l]}, {Black, Line[l]}}
```

[image]

Also the filling goes outside the boundary.

Any ideas to fix this behavior?

#### EDIT

Searching here I try this

```
g = 
  ParametricPlot[curve[1][q], {q, 0, 2*Pi}, 
    Axes -> False, 
    PlotPoints -> 50, 
    PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.007]] 

line = Cases[g, l_Line :> First @ l, Infinity];

Graphics[
  {Opacity[0.4], Darker @ Orange, EdgeForm[Darker @ Orange], Polygon[line]}, 
  Options[g]]
```

[image]

The polygon is still evident, but this time the filling does not go outside the boundary.

Comment: What is `curve`?

Comment: Even without `curve` I think that the problem can be solved with `Exclusions->None`.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to add the definitions. Not it should be ok!

Comment: @ybeltukov: You are right! Adding `Exclusions->None` did indeed solve the issue! Amazing without even seeing the definitions. Thanks!

Comment: Why `Exclusions->None` is necessary here?

Comment: @dimitris Just to obtain one curve. You have a piecewise function and you should specify that you have a continuous curve. It is not a workaround. It is documented and expected behavior.

Comment: Ok. Now I got it. I understood why it was put in hold. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is worth posting an answer, but nevertheless here it goes (code adopted by a discussion with David Park several years ago; then working with Mathematica 5.2. I tried to upgrade it in order to fit `Graphics` structure of recent versions):

```
partitionfunction[d_][q_] := 
  Piecewise[{
    {Sin[(Pi*q)/(2*d)]^2, Inequality[0, LessEqual, q, Less, d]}, 
    {1, Inequality[d, LessEqual, q, Less, 2*Pi - d]}, 
    {Sin[(Pi*(2*Pi - q))/(2*d)]^2, 2*Pi - d <= q <= 2*Pi}}]

radius[d_][q_] := 1 + 1.5*partitionfunction[d][q]*BesselJ[5, (13/(2*Pi))*q + 5]

curve[d_][q_] := radius[d][q]*{Cos[q], Sin[q]}

g = 
  ParametricPlot[curve[1][q], {q, 0, 2*Pi}, 
    Axes -> False, 
    PlotPoints -> 50, 
    PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.007], 
    Exclusions -> None];

line = Cases[g, l_Line :> First@l, Infinity];

Graphics[
  {Opacity[0.4], Darker @ Orange, EdgeForm[Darker @ Orange], Polygon[line]}, 
  Options[g]]
```

[image]

This question and answer is related to the reply I wanted to give [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99754/how-to-make-a-blob-in-3d)

Thanks to ybeltukov for pointing out `Exclusions` (which I should have known that it has to be applied here).