# Interpolating 3D noisy data

Tags: interpolation

I have some noisy 3D data that looks like this:

```
SeedRandom[0];
data = Join @@ Table[{x, y, Sin[x*y] + RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 0.2]]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.2}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, 0.2}];
```

I would like to find a smooth interpolation for the data, like the one in this answer (which only works for 2D data): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162145

How can I do this?

Comment: Also [this answer for making random pebbles](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134405/34008) might be of interest. (And, no, it does not do what OP wants.)

Comment: You might want to use `RLink` in *Mathematica* and use the `gam` function in the `mgcv` package.  `gam` stands for "generalized additive model".  (Note that this is not a "generalized linear model" which *Mathematica* does support as `GeneralizedLinearModelFit`.)

Answer (score 1):

The following approach is somewhat simplistic and limited but it might be good enough.

**1.** We find Quantile Regression fit for each data subset corresponding to a unique x-axis value. We make a x-value dispatch function that gives a z-value for a pair of x-and-y values.

**2.** We find Quantile Regression fit for each data subset corresponding to a unique y-axis value. We make a y-value dispatch function that gives a z-value for a pair of x-and-y values.

**3.** We make the function `QFunc` that averages the values of the distpatch functions.

**4.** We apply `QFunc` over the same x-y-grid of the original data.

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/QuantileRegression.m"]

nKnots = 9;

(* 1 *)
qXFuncs = 
  Association[#[[1, 1]] -> 
      QuantileRegression[#[[All, {2, 3}]], nKnots, {0.5}][[1]] & /@ 
    GatherBy[data, #[[1]] &]];

(* 2 *)
qYFuncs = 
  Association[#[[1, 2]] -> 
      QuantileRegression[#[[All, {1, 3}]], nKnots, {0.5}][[1]] & /@ 
    GatherBy[data, #[[2]] &]];

(* 3 *)
QFunc[x_, y_] := Mean[{qXFuncs[x][y], qYFuncs[y][x]}];

(* 4 *)
dataSmooth = 
  Join @@ Table[{x, y, QFunc[x, y]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.2}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, 0.2}];

GraphicsGrid[{{
  ListPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "Original data"],    
  ListPlot3D[dataSmooth, PlotRange -> MinMax[data[[All, 3]]], PlotLabel -> "Smoothed data"]}}, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]